# How many words of length $n$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a, b, c\}$ exist in which each letter appears at least once?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, computer-science, formal-languages

> Let $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$ and $ n \in \mathbb N$. How many words of
>   length  $n$ over the alphabet $\Sigma$ exist in which each letter
>   appears at least once?

I know how to  computation for words without the restriction that each letter appears at least once. So my specific difficulty is how to handle the restriction

Comment: Do you want a formula or a suggestion for a method? Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: @ MarcvanLeeuwen I know how compute it, if  the problem is without the condition that each letter appears at least once.

Comment: @AnnaSaabel  You should edit your question to include your computation for words without the restriction and explain in the question that your difficulty is that you do not know how to handle the restriction that each letter appears at least once.  That way users of this site will know that you have thought about the question yourself and know what specific difficulty must be addressed in their answers.  Questions that show no effort are not well-received here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(f_n)$ be the desired sequence. You can use exponential generating functions to find the answer too. Note that
$$
F(x)=(x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dotsb)^3
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2++k_2=n;\, k_i>0} \binom{n}{k_1, k_2, k_3}\right) \frac{x^n}{n!}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n \frac{x^n}{n!}.
\tag{1}
$$

But we also have that
$$
F(x)=(e^x-1)^3=e^{3x}-3e^{2x}+3e^{x}-1=-1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(
3^n-3\times2^n+3
\right)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}
$$
In particular
$$
f_n=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $n=0$;}\\
3^n-3\times2^n+3 & \text{if $n>0$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by inclusion-exclusion. Count all the words, remove those that don't use $a$ and those that don't use $b$, and those that don't use $c$, then for every pair add back the number that don't use any of the pair. Finally subtract of the possibility that does not use any letters at all (this only affects the value for $n=0$).

That's $3^n-3\times2^n+3\times1-0^n$, sequence starts $(0,0,0,6,36,150,540,1806,5796,18150,\ldots)$.